# How to use user input from selectors in javascript?

Tags: javascript, select

I was following code academy on making a rock paper scissors game.
I wanted to make a select option where the user can select either Rock, Paper, or Scissors. When I made the submit button, I wanted the selected option to be transferred to the main function which pops up an alert telling whether if it was a tie or a win. However, when I press the submit button nothing happens... Here is my code:

```
<h1> Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
                        <form action="" onsubmit="return Winner()">
                                <h3> Select Your Move</h3>
                                <select id="moves">
                                    <option value="rock">Rock</option>
                                    <option value="paper">Paper</option>
                                    <option value="scissors">Scissors</option>
                                    </select>
                                <br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button">
                        </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Winner(){

if (document.getElementById("moves").value = "rock"
    var userChoice = "rock";
else if (document.getElementById("moves").value = "paper"
    var userChoice = "paper";
else (document.getElementById("moves").value = "scissors"
    var userChoice = "scissors"

 var computerChoice = Math.random();
        if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
             computerChoice = "rock";
        } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
            computerChoice = "paper";
        } else {
            computerChoice = "scissors";
        }

var compare = function(userChoice, computerChoice) {

    if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
        return ("Computer picked" + " " + computerChoice + "." + " " + "The result is a tie!" + "\n Refresh the page to play again!")
    }
    else if (userChoice === "rock") {
        if (computerChoice === "scissors")
        return ("Computer picked" + " " + computerChoice + "," + " " + "you win!");
        else { 
            return ("Computer picked" + " " + computerChoice + "," + " " + "you lose!")}
    }
    else if (userChoice === "paper") {
        if (computerChoice === "rock")
        return ("Computer picked" + " " + computerChoice + "," + " " + "you win!");
        else { 
            return ("Computer picked" + " " + computerChoice + "," + " " + "you lose!")}
    }
    else {
        if (computerChoice === "rock")
        return ("Computer picked" + " " + computerChoice + "," + " " + "you win!");
        else { 
            return ("Computer picked" + " " + computerChoice + "," + " " + "you lose!")}
    }  
}

alert(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
}
        </script>
```

Comment: This might or might not be the problem, but your if/else statements are missing closing parenthesis. Also you should use `==` to compare: `if (document.getElementById("moves").value == "rock")`

Comment: Post your javascript code on code review site :P

Comment: Your code contains multiple syntax and logical errors. Missing semicolon, missing ), using = instead of == in if statement. Fix those first.

Comment: @gab06 code review site's work is to *review* the *working* code.

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax errors that are causing your issues see the comments below:

Keep in mind that `==` checks equality while `=` sets a value

```js
function Winner(){

if (document.getElementById("moves").value == "rock") // you were mising a `=` and a `)` here, `==` checks equality, `=` sets a vale
    var userChoice = "rock";
else if (document.getElementById("moves").value == "paper") // you were mising a `=` and a `)` here
    var userChoice = "paper";
else (document.getElementById("moves").value == "scissors") // you were mising a `=` and a `)` here
    var userChoice = "scissors"; //missing `;` here

 var computerChoice = Math.random();
        if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
             computerChoice = "rock";
        } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
            computerChoice = "paper";
        } else {
            computerChoice = "scissors";
        }

var compare = function(userChoice, computerChoice) {

    if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
        return ("Computer picked" + " " + computerChoice + "." + " " + "The result is a tie!" + "\n Refresh the page to play again!")
    }
    else if (userChoice === "rock") {
        if (computerChoice === "scissors")
        return ("Computer picked" + " " + computerChoice + "," + " " + "you win!");
        else { 
            return ("Computer picked" + " " + computerChoice + "," + " " + "you lose!")}
    }
    else if (userChoice === "paper") {
        if (computerChoice === "rock")
        return ("Computer picked" + " " + computerChoice + "," + " " + "you win!");
        else { 
            return ("Computer picked" + " " + computerChoice + "," + " " + "you lose!")}
    }
    else {
        if (computerChoice === "rock")
        return ("Computer picked" + " " + computerChoice + "," + " " + "you win!");
        else { 
            return ("Computer picked" + " " + computerChoice + "," + " " + "you lose!")}
    }  
}

alert(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
}
```

```html
<h1> Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
                        <form action="" onsubmit="return Winner()">
                                <h3> Select Your Move</h3>
                                <select id="moves">
                                    <option value="rock">Rock</option>
                                    <option value="paper">Paper</option>
                                    <option value="scissors">Scissors</option>
                                    </select>
                                <br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button">
                        </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your JS console as there's a syntax error in your Winner() function (where you set the `userChoice` variable. That should do the trick ...

Comment: @downvoter: to learn from my mistakes it would be helpful to know what's the down vote for ... thanks